# Django category model used in multiple models (belongs_to)

Tags: python, django

I have one Category model that I'd like to use in other models instead of creating different models for each case.

Each model (Page, Article,...) has its own set of categories.

Table Category
id
content_type (Article, Page,...)

Table Page
id
category_id (form select filter with content_type Page)

Table Article
id
category_id (form select filter with content_type Article)

I can't use a polymorphic relationship since I don't have to store the id.
So how can I represent that in my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class ContentTypes(models.TextChoices):
        PAGE = 'Page'
        ARTICLE = 'Article'
        RECIPE = 'Recipe'

    content_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        choices=ContentTypes.choices,
        default=ContentTypes.PAGE,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        limit_choices_to={'content_type': 'Page'},
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```